# SAPUI5 Fiori app warning Can't remove control from a non-managed category id: _POPOVER_?

Tags: sapui5, reload, sap-fiori

While Navigating to home from Fiori Header and also reloading the page it's taking more time to reload and navigating to Home.
in the console, I have seen many warnings repeatedly like
**Can't remove control from a non-managed category id: *POPOVER*** .

all these making my app navigation to home and reloading makes slow.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks,
G Srinu

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the app has a popover which has not been destroyed when the user selects home (on the launchpad).  The popover should be destroyed when the app is exited.

Comment: Yes, @SAP Fiori Crew you are correct but App does not have any direct popover. SAPUI5 internally treating the Dropdown visible area as a popover. and I am using the drop-down for each row in a table. That's the reason it making multiple times this warning in the console.

Comment: Can you please show your view definition and controller?